# How can I cross-check a large csv file of email addresses against Salesforce data?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-loader, data

We use Salesforce Marketing Cloud and have thousands of records that don't appear to be in Salesforce. Hence, I want to delete these records so the two systems are in sync and we can save some money in database size.

I have a Data Extension of several thousand Email Addresses from Leads and Contacts.

**I would like to know the best/easiest way to cross-check and verify this list against Salesforce data, so I can be sure it's safe to delete the records from SFMC.**

Has anyone else battled a similar scenario? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you wanting to "delete records" from - your data extension with several records, All Subscribers, Contact Builder Contacts or all of the above?

Comment: @Macca - all of the above.

Comment: Thanks. So, is the problem that these records have already been sent to and are counting towards your Contacts count for billing purposes and you want to clear marketing cloud out of non-CRM based data? Or are you intending to use this CSV data to send with in some way? Just need to be clear what we're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Use Data Loader or Dataloader.io to export all Leads and Contacts with the email field. Create a single google workbook or excel workbook to cross-check the resulting lists with your Data Extension emails.

[Here's some instructions on doing this in excel](https://trumpexcel.com/compare-two-columns/)

Comment: @ayloola - thank you for the suggestion. Is there any other way of doing it without exporting data from Salesforce, but running the query against data in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

To extract data from lead and contact use data loader. Use Vlookup in Excel to cross-check against salesforce data.